# Set a custom queryset (select_related) for a list field in the admin change page?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have an using the Django admin interface to manage a lot of objects, and one of the page is giving me issue, this page has a field to a related object (Foreign Key) that has a `__str__` that also goes to its related objects, this make a lot of queries and is barely useable (Around 3000 queries to show the page as there are a LOT of objects).

I would like to know if there is a way to set a custom queryset ? I would like to add a select_related or prefetch_related to this element.

The part causing issue is this certificate requests list :

[image]

The page model (Certificate has the following attribute:

```
class Certificate(models.Model):

    certificate_request = models.OneToOneField(
        "CertificateRequest",
        verbose_name=_("Certificate request"),
        related_name="certificate",
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

And the related model has this :

```
class CertificateRequest(models.Model):

    domain = models.ForeignKey(
        "Domain",
        verbose_name=_("Domain"),
        related_name="certificate_requests"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return "{state} certificate request for {domain} from {creation_date}".format(
            state=dict(self.STATUS).get(self.status),
            domain=self.domain.fqdn,
            creation_date=self.creation_date
        )
```

What would be the way to fix this ? How can I set a queryset on this part ?

EDIT: I added more informations.
I tried using a custom form, but this didn't do any change :

```
class CertificateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    certificate_request = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CertificateRequest.objects.select_related("domain"))

    class Meta:
        model = Certificate
        fields = "__all__"


@admin.register(Certificate)
class CertificateAdmin(CompareVersionAdmin):
    model = Certificate

    class Meta:
        form = CertificateForm
```

Comment: Is this a field you actually need to change (show in the form)? Can it not be derived based on the users domain selection?

Comment: The field should not be changed once defined, it only needs to be shown on new certificates, I've overrided get_readonly_fields to make it read only (So not doing those queries) if the field is already set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [custom `ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) for your admin where you specify a  [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) for the `ForeignKey`. Here you can specify the `queryset` parameter:

```
# forms.py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    certificate_request = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CertReq.objects.foo().bar())
    #                                               select/prefetch-------^^^^^^^^^^^

    class Meta:
        model = Foo

# admin.py
class YourAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
```

Comment: In what ModelAdmin should I put it ? Again the problem is not on the query set of the current AdminModel but in the list of all the objects or another model so that they get listed as possible values for the foreign key (but they are not actually bound to the current object)

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution but that didn't change anything. I updated the origin post with more information.

Comment: DId you put `form = myForm` in the class `Meta` of the admin? Admin classes usually do not have a Meta

Comment: That was the issue :)
Thank you very much.

I was surprised that it's not using Meta, how would you do if you have a model attribute called form ?

Comment: The model has a Meta. The admin does not. You don't have to give your admin more attributes, but if you do, do not accidentally override existing ones :)

Answer (score -1):

The [`get_object` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L658) on the ModelAdmin class is what is responsible for retrieving the object to edit. You could certainly extend that method in your subclass to use select_related as necessary.

Comment: As far as I know, the get_object is to get the current object opened in the page ? Here the problem is in the part that gets the list of all the objects that could be related but that are not actually bound by the current object) (So the list of the possible values for the foreign key)